# Test simple c# code expressions in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, code-testing

I'd like to know how should I do to test simple C# expressions

1) in Visual Studio and
  2) not in debug, in design mode

Say, I want to verify what will return this code

```
?DateTime.ParseExact("2016", "yyyy")
```

Or

```
int i;
int.TryParse("x55", out i);
?i
```

I obtained in the immediate window the following message:

> ```
> ?DateTime.ParseExact("2016", "yyyy") 
> The expression cannot be evaluated while in design mode.
> ```

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski see my remark

Comment: Immediate is for during debugging. You need View-->other windows-->command window.

Comment: @HimBromBeere the second exercice not working in command window, nor the first one

Comment: The [Interactive Window](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough) should do what you're looking for - `View > Other Windows > C# Interactive`

Comment: @Diado, please read carefully the OP

Comment: @Serge I did, I said _Interactive_, not _immediate_.

Comment: Not really an answer to what you are asking, but I highly recommend you try out [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

Comment: @Selvin DateTime.ParseExact("2016", "yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Command "DateTime.ParseExact("2016"," is not valid.

Comment: @DavidG, not really, I ask about tools integrated in Visual Studio

Comment: Yes, but this tool replaces VS for a lot of my tasks, especially testing snippets of code.

Comment: @Diado could you write an answer, that remark helped me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Interactive Window](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough) (not to be confused with the *immediate window*) will achieve what you're looking for.

It can be accessed by `View > Other Windows > C# Interactive`, and is essentially an interactive compiler session that runs independently of whether the project is being executed or not, allowing you to arbitrarily execute code without having to build and run your project.

Here is an example of what can be done in this window

```
> Random gen = new Random();
> DateTime RandomDay()
. {
.     int monthsBack = 1;
.     int monthsForward = 3;
.     DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-monthsBack);
.     DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(monthsForward);    
.     int range = (endDate - startDate).Days;
.     return startDate.AddDays(gen.Next(range));
. }
> RandomDay()
[28/01/2020 15:11:51]
```

and also using external dlls

```
> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse("{'myArticle': { 'myDate': '2020-03-24T00:00:00'}  }")
(1,1): error CS0103: The name 'Newtonsoft' does not exist in the current context

> #r "C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"

> Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse("{'myArticle': { 'myDate': '2020-03-24T00:00:00'}  }")
JObject(1) { JProperty(1) { JObject(3) { JProperty(1) { [24/03/2020 00:00:00] } } } }
```

Comment: would add that there is a way to add missing dll references in that tool via `> #r "C:\Users\myUser\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\...Newtonsoft.Json.dll"`

Comment: ... added to answer that info

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware it could do that!

Comment: is there any more user friendly way to import nugets besides typing all this `C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.2\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll` ?

Answer (score 3):

immediate window will not work in design mode. you need to use "C# interactive window", which is build on top of Roslyn  hence install Roslyn then  follow below Wiki

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window

C# Interactive window open by below menu path:

Views > Other Windows > C# Interactive

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your issue on Visual Studio 2019 ,

1. first I install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Newtonsoft.json using nuget package manager.
2. second using this method defined in static non generic class to dump any expression you want to verify.

   ```
     public static void DumpObject(this object value)    
     {

      Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented));  

     }
   ```

N.B: remember to add using Newtonsoft.Json;

3. finally form Main method invoke Class.YourDumpMethod(AnyObjToVerify);
   as follow:

   ```
   static void Main()

   {

    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2016","yyyy", null, DateTimeStyles.None);

    Dump.DumpObject(dt);

    int i;

    bool b = int.TryParse("55", out i);

    Dump.DumpObject(i);

   }
   ```

Hoping it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external application for this, like [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/):

[image: Screenshot of LINQPad]

Or the Jupyter notebook in [Try .NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/try-dotnet):

[image: Screenshot from the code editor of Try .NET]

Comment: thank you for the answer, but the OP mentionned in the fist point "in Visual Studio"